# Is there a way to set up start viewing position in excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

Normally Excel remembers where you stopped at a sheet and when you open it next time it takes you right there. Is there a way to set up such a position when generating the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) package, you can control Excel with COM and automate anything that Excel can do.

Here's an example that creates a simple worksheet, initializes some cells, selects a cell, then saves the document.  When you later open the document it will restore to that same location.

```
import win32com.client

def create_excel_file():
    xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    # xl.Visible = True # Uncomment to make the Excel COM instance visible
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
    ws = xl.ActiveSheet
    ws.Range('A1').Value = 100
    ws.Range('A2').Value = 200
    ws.Range('B1').Value = 300
    ws.Range('B2').Value = 400
    ws.Range('B2').Select()
    ws.SaveAs(r'test.xlsx')
    xl.Quit()

create_excel_file()
```

Here's the resulting file opened in Excel:

[image: test.xlsx content]

Answer (score 0):

Say we want *Sheet2* to be the active sheet and cell **Z100** to be at the upper left-hand corner of the window.  Place this event macro in the workbook code area:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("Z100").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:=ActiveCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Scroll:=True
End Sub
```

Because it is workbook code, it is very easy to install and use:

1. right-click the tiny Excel icon just to the left of File on the Menu Bar
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (workbook code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Macros must be enabled for this to work!

Comment: Since the OP tagged the question `python`,  they probably want the answer in Python.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  Then I will remove this answer after a Python-based solution is posted...thank you...